# Access 2013: UPDATE-statement with conditions and corresponding values stored in another table

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, multiple-conditions

Working with MS-Access 2013, I have a table (*Table_1*) which contains a list of properties for several products (identified by an *ID*) in long format (i.e. several rows (up to 500) per product, albeit the row count may differ between products):

```
ID  | Characteristics
----|------------------
1   | characteristc_a
1   | characteristc_aa
1   | characteristc_c
2   | characteristc_b
2   | characteristc_d
```

Depending on which characteristics a particular product has, it is said to either have a particular property or not. How characteristics “translate” into properties is defined in another table, *Table_2*:

```
Characteristics    | Attribute     | Value
-------------------|---------------|---------
characteristic_a   |  Property_1   |  prop_1a
characteristic_aa  |  Property_1   |  prop_1a
characteristic_b   |  Property_1   |  prop_1b
characteristic_c   |  Property_2   |  prop_2
characteristic_d   |  Property_3   |  prop_3
```

For example, if a product's value for the attribute *Characteristics* is either '*characteristic_a*' or '*characteristic_aa*' (or both), its value for the attribute *Property_1* should be ‘*prop_1a*’. If, instead, its value for Characteristics is '*characteristic_b*', the corresponding value for the attribute *Property_1* should be ‘*prop_1b*’ etc.

Finally, Table_3 collects all properties of all products in wide format (i.e. exactly one row per product):

```
ID   | Property_1 | Property_2 | Property_3
-----|------------|------------|------------
1    |  prop_1a   |  prop_2    |  NULL
2    |  prop_1b   |  NULL      |  prop_3
```

I already succeeded at directly coding the conditions from Table_2 into the update statement, e.g. by using something like

```
UPDATE Table_3
SET    Property_1 = ‘prop_1a’
WHERE  ('characteristic_a')  IN (SELECT Characteristics FROM Table_1 WHERE Table_3.ID = Table_1.ID)
    OR ('characteristic_aa') IN (SELECT Characteristics FROM Table_1 WHERE Table_3.ID = Table_1.ID)
```

(Since I am not too familiar with SQL, even this might be a clumsy way to code it)

However, the “mapping table” *Table_2* contains more than 2,000 entries and, hence, coding all these conditions would be quite cumbersome. Instead, I would like the UPDATE statement to automatically take conditions and the resulting actions from Table_2, e.g. in pseudo-code something like:

```
UPDATE Table_3
SET    Property_1 = [Appropriate value from Table_2] 
WHERE  [In all the entries of Table_1 with the same ID as the current row in Table_3] 
       [The attribute Characteristics in Table_1] IN 
       [The terms listed in Table_2 for the attribute Property_1]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why choose 1b for product 1 property 1? Does the highest (alphabetically) characteristic have precedence?

Answer (score 0):

Table_2 should have an ID field and this ID should be saved into Table_1 as foreign key instead of the lengthy descriptive value.

Build a query that joins the two tables on the primary and foreign key fields. Pull the descriptive text fields into the query and then switch to CROSSTAB design. Set appropriate Row and Column and Value fields. Row would be Table_1 ID (which could be more descriptive such as ProdID_FK), Column would be Table_2 Attribute and Value would be Table_2 Value. Use the Max function on the Value field.

Consider:

```
TRANSFORM Max(Table2.CharValue) AS MaxOfCharValue
SELECT Table1.ProdID_FK
FROM Table2 RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.CharID = Table1.CharID_FK
GROUP BY Table1.ProdID_FK
PIVOT Table2.Attribute;
```

This produces the example output from the sample data.

Probably should not use Value as a name for anything has it has special meaning.